# SELECT query with an INNER JOIN crashing phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a simple `SELECT` query that I'm running on a MySQL database, with information stored in the MyISAM storage engine. However, when I `INNER JOIN` a large table (~ 1.3mil rows, approx. 100 columns), the query fails to execute and I get a hanging process in phpMyAdmin.

Is there any way I can rework this query to pull out the relevant information I need, that uses less resources?

```
SELECT exhibitor_id, company_name FROM guidein
    INNER JOIN webmaster ON exhibitor_id = source_id 
    WHERE guidein.db_table = '$db_table' // i.e. 'PX14EX'
    ORDER BY company_name
```

`exhibitor_id` can be found in the `guidein` table.

`company_name` can be found in the `webmaster` table.

`source_id` can also be found in the `webmaster` table.

`db_table` is found in both tables.

Answer (score 0):

Your query would probably benefit from indexes.  Try these:

```
create index idx_guidein_db_table_exhibitor_id on guidein(db_table, exhibitor_id);
create index idx_webmaster_source_id_company_name on webmaster(source_id, company_name);
```

Of course, if your query is pulling hundreds of thousands or millions of rows, that might be the cause of the performance problem.  If so, indexes will not be a big help.